# Accessing Published Artifacts from yaml pipeline tasks

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a PowerShell task that processes published artifacts from another stage.

I have noticed these are put into a folder "s". Random sampling shows its "s" all the time but I doubt if it will be the case always!

Wondering what's the best way to refer to these files safely?

Here's my publish artifacts task:

[image: Publish Task]

Published artifacts:

[image: Published artifacts]

And the PowerShell task that consumes these artifacts:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The variable that you use does not work with the `s` folder. As described on the documentation `Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory` is the local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before being pushed to their destination. For example: `c:\agent_work\1\a` . You will find those files under `a` folder. The folder that is referred with the `s` letter is where the sources are downloaded `Build.SourcesDirectory`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Documentation on Azure devops predefined variables that can be used and where the folders are located.

https://blog.geralexgr.com/devops/how-azure-devops-pipelines-agent-works

Answer (score 1):

The predefined variable you are looking for is $(Pipeline.Workspace). If you look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) for the download pipeline artifact task you can see the default path. Note if you are downloading more than one artifact they will be within subfolders

Edit - Having just looked again at the pipeline are you publishing and downloading the artifact, or are you just doing all of these tasks as a single pipeline?
The best way imo to have these setup would be to have two pipelines. The CI to build and publish the artifact, then the CD pipeline to download and use the artifact

Comment: So  $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory) will point me to local path of the agent where src code gets downloaded - to access the downloaded artifacts, I will still have to go ...\artifactsname\s\my_files

Comment: @Sudipta-Mukherjee Apologise, I got the variable slightly wrong. I've update my answer with the correct one